# Question about the react-redux documentation

Tags: react-redux

I am confused by something on the react-redux documentation

https://redux-docs.netlify.com/recipes/configuring-your-store/

specifically, in attempting to build the prototype app (which is provided here https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos/src), I am confused about the line

```
import rootReducer from './reducers'
```

what is confusing is that in the app directory, there is no such file reducers.js, there is only a folder `reducers/` which contains

```
index.js
todos.js
todos.spec.js
visibilityFilter.js
```

I see no file for rootReducer, so I am assuming (correctly?) that the ES6 syntax for the above code is importing the *default export* from

`reducers/index.js`

is that correct?

In that file, I see

```
export default combineReducers({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
})
```

do I understand correctly the defaulted export anonymous function, exported from `reducers/index.js`, is then imported into `index.js` as `rootReducer` ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  That's ES6 "default export" syntax, combined with an `index.js` file.  When an `index.js` file exists in a folder, you can specify just the folder name in the import statement, and the bundler knows to look at `index.js` automatically.

Comment: right, a lot of the Redux examples I am going through use the same pattern. it is just jarring when you first look at it because there's a folder called `reducers/` but not a file called `reducers.js` like your other `import ... from '...' ` statements

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing Redux-specific about this.  It's a pattern that was standardized by Node.js years ago.